# Only one word is reading from .txt file

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am implementing a Feature,

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to read and work on `.txt` file BUT when i write one word then it works fine BUT when i write two words then it is not working.

views.py

```
def defining(request):
    with open('wordlists.txt') as in_file:
        wordlist = in_file.read().splitlines()
    
    posts = Post.exclude.exclude(reduce(operator.and_,(Q(description__contains=x) for x in wordlist)))


    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'defining.html', context)
```

wordlists.txt

```
good
bad
```

When i add `good` word ( only one word ) then it works fine BUT when i add `bad` after good then both doesn't work.

I have no idea, where is the mistake.
Any help would be Appreciated.
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: You need to move along each line in the file and change the `read` to within the `open`?

Comment: You likely want to use `operator.or_` iso `operator.and_`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you very Much.  choosing **operator.or_** worked correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `operator._or` as reducer, not `operator._and`, since you want to exclude that contain the word good, or the word bad, et.

You do not need to work with `reduce`, since Django has defined some arithmetic for `Q` objects. You can define this as:

```
posts = Post.objects.exclude(
    Q(
        *[Q(description__contains=x) for x in wordlist],
        _connector=Q.OR
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **operator._or** instead of `operator.and__` AND IT WORKED CORRECTLY.

**Where `operator.or_`** ?

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce

def defining(request):
    with open('wordlists.txt') as in_file:
        wordlist = in_file.read().split()

    posts = Post.objects.exclude(reduce(operator.or_,(Q(description__contains=x) for x in wordlist)))

HERE----------------------------------------------^
```